# Does Java library have functions like std::lower_bound() , std::upper_bound() in C++ ?

Tags: java, c++, lower-bound, upperbound

Are there any other alternatives to achieve the same in Java ?
In C++, I can use these wonderful methods and make my life easier. Is it possible in Java too ?
My sole aim is to write code which is simple and clean and which is not error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Java class [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which is based on search tree of comparable objects instead of hash table has similar methods [`floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29) and [`ceiling`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling%28E%29). More generic methods for any iterable type you are free to implement by yourself.